# Firefox renders fine only after refresh

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a website that looks fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, immediately after loading, it resizes the whole website. All items have an offset or they`re broken.

But if I hit refresh, F5 or ctr+F5, everything looks fine.

Why is that? Why does it needs to clear cache before looking alright?

The website is: [HERE](http://inner-pride.ro/clients/ibc)

Comment: Try moving script from `$(document).ready` to `$(window).load`

Comment: Nope, I already tried that, still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear browser cache.
In my browser (Mozilla firefox 26.0) it looks ok. (at first load and also after refresh)

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: Nope, still the same, sorry.